# Task Scheduler takes minutes to get to Create Task Process

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

I have a server which I have an app running very often..  If I run my app manually it takes seconds to run and finish.  If I let Task Scheduler do it it takes 4-5 minutes.  I look at the task history and from the Action Started event to the Create Task Process event is over 2.5 minutes..  Does anyone know what it is doing in this period of time?  This is on a Windows server with many users attaching by Terminal Services..

Many thanks

Derek.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Task Scheduler sets priority level to low by default. This allows other things to run without interruption. The assumption here is that something on the scheduler is not meant to go RIGHT at that time but generally at that time. If this is not the case, you can change the process priority.

Something else at play is memory priority. It will default to 4 instead of 5. You need to boost both in settings to get it to run with higher priority. If you don't need the timing to be exact, leave it so that other applications have priority to resources.

You can observe process priority with this tool: [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)

You can set it with scripting too. [See MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383512(v=vs.85).aspx)  for this. You'll be setting `TaskSettings.Priority`.

> **Task priority / Priority Class / Priority Level**
>
> - 0  REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL
> - 1  HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS THREAD_PRIORITY_HIGHEST
> - 2  ABOVE_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS THREAD_PRIORITY_ABOVE_NORMAL
> - 3  ABOVE_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS THREAD_PRIORITY_ABOVE_NORMAL
> - 4  NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS   THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL
> - 5  NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS   THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL
> - 6  NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS   THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL
> - 7  BELOW_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS THREAD_PRIORITY_BELOW_NORMAL
> - 8  BELOW_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS THREAD_PRIORITY_BELOW_NORMAL
> - 9  IDLE_PRIORITY_CLASS THREAD_PRIORITY_LOWEST
> - 10 IDLE_PRIORITY_CLASS THREAD_PRIORITY_IDLE